# Get disassembled bytes from assembler code

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, disassembly

I'm wondering if there is any program that can convert my assembler code into disassembled bytes like so:

```
mov 0×01, %eax to B8 01 00 00 00
```

Is there any trick I don't see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such a tool is called an [assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler). To get raw (flat) machine code, you can use `nasm` for example (x86 assumed):

```
nasm -f bin foo.s -o foo.bin
```

Comment: Yeah how can i write the assembler code first. I tried BITS 32
mov $eax, 0x1
mov $rax, 0x1 to write that to a file and then to assemble it with command "nasm" but i get error symbol rax undefinded

Comment: @DavidEhlen For that, you'll need to consult Google for an assembly tutorial.